# mongocxx error in qt project (undefined reference to `__imp__ZN8mongocxx7v_noabi8instanceC1Ev')

Tags: mongodb, qt, mongo-cxx-driver

i'm trying to use mongocxx in my qt project, but i've encountered with this problem:
(undefined reference to __imp__ZN8mongocxx7v_noabi8instanceC1Ev).
My compiler is MinGW 64-bit, mongocxx version is 3.9.0.
Any ideas?
[main.cpp with mongocxx code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNCdi.png)
[.pro file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gyiBB.png)
I tried to solve this problem, but the same problem other people encountered was solved by changing the compiler version, so idk what to do
.pro file

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

CONFIG += c++17

# You can make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

INCLUDEPATH += \
C:/mongo-cxx-driver/include/mongocxx/v_noabi \
C:/mongo-cxx-driver/include/bsoncxx/v_noabi \

LIBS += \
-LC:/mongo-cxx-driver/lib \
-lmongocxx \
-lbsoncxx \

SOURCES += \
    main.cpp \
    mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS += \
    mainwindow.h

FORMS += \
    mainwindow.ui

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

mistake

```
error: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN8mongocxx7v_noabi8instanceC1Ev'
```

Comment: Is mongocxx compiled for MingGW? I doubt so. You can not mix MSVC and MinGW c++ libraries as they have different ABIs.